# Khmer page number in beamer

Tags: beamer, page-numbering, polyglossia, lastpage

I have just translated **gloss-khmer.ldf**, which is a part of the **polyglossia** package. 
I have tried to use it with the **beamer** class using theme **Madrid**.
The theorem number is displayed as a **Khmer** number but the last page number is still an **Arabic** number.
So how can I change the last page number from **Arabic** to **Khmer**?
Here is my **beamerkhmer.tex**:

```
\documentclass[xetex,serif]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]

\usetheme{Madrid}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newfontfamily\khmerfont[Script=Khmer]{Khmer OS}
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=khmer]{khmer}
\XeTeXlinebreaklocale “KHM”

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{theorem}
            Please see the bottom right conner\newline
            [\alert{current page in Khmer}]/[\alert{last page in Arabic}]\newline
        \end{theorem}
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{theorem}
            How can I change the \alert{last page} from Arabic to Khmer?
        \end{theorem}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and this is my **gloss-khmer.ldf**

```
\ProvidesFile{gloss-khmer.ldf}[polyglossia: module for Khmer]
\PolyglossiaSetup{khmer}{
  script=Khmer,
  scripttag=khmr,
  langtag=KHM,
  hyphennames={nohyphenation},
  fontsetup=true,
  %TODO localalph={xxx@alph,xxx@Alph}
  %TODO localdigits=khmernumber
}

\newif\if@khmer@numerals
\def\tmp@khmer{khmer}
\define@key{khmer}{numerals}[arabic]{%
    \def\@tmpa{#1}%
    \ifx\@tmpa\tmp@khmer\@khmer@numeralstrue\else
      \@khmer@numeralsfalse\fi
}

\setkeys{khmer}{numerals}

\def\captionskhmer{%
  \def\prefacename{អារម្ភកថា}%
  \def\refname{ឯកសារយោង}%
  \def\abstractname{សង្ខេប}%
  \def\bibname{គន្ថនិទ្ទេស}%
  \def\chaptername{ជំពួក}%
  \def\appendixname{បន្ថែម}%
  \def\contentsname{មាតិការ}%
  \def\listfigurename{បញ្ជីរូបភាព}%
  \def\listtablename{បញ្ជីតារាង}%
  \def\indexname{សន្ទស្សន៍}%
  \def\figurename{រូប}%
  \def\tablename{តារាង}%
  \def\partname{ផ្នែក}%
  \def\pagename{ទំព័រ}%
  \def\seename{មើល}%
  \def\alsoname{មើលបន្ថែម}%
  \def\enclname{ឯកសារភ្ជាប់}%
  \def\ccname{ចម្លងជួន}%
  \def\headtoname{ផ្ញើរទៅ}%
  \def\proofname{សម្រាយ}%
  \def\glossaryname{សទានុក្រម}% 
}
\def\datekhmer{%   
   \def\khmer@month{%
     \ifcase\month\or
      មករា\or
      កុម្ភៈ\or
      មិនា\or
      មេសា\or
      ឧសភា\or
      មិថុនា\or
      កក្ដដា\or
      សីហា\or
      កញ្ញា\or
      តុលា\or
      វិច្ឆិកា\or
      ធ្នូ\fi}%
   \def\today{\khmernumber\day \space \khmer@month \space \khmernumber\year}%
}

\def\khmerdigits#1{\expandafter\@khmer@digits #1@}
\def\@khmer@digits#1{%
  \ifx @#1% then terminate
  \else
    \ifx0#1០\else\ifx1#1១\else\ifx2#1២\else\ifx3#1៣\else\ifx4#1៤\else\ifx5#1៥\else\ifx6#1៦\else\ifx7#1៧\else\ifx8#1៨\else\ifx9#1៩\else#1\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
    \expandafter\@khmer@digits
  \fi
}

\def\khmernumber#1{%
  \if@khmer@numerals
    \khmerdigits{\number#1}%
  \else
    \number#1%
  \fi}

\def\khmer@globalnumbers{%
   \let\orig@arabic\@arabic%
   \let\@arabic\khmernumber%
   \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\protect\khmernumber{\c@footnote}}%
}
\def\nokhmer@globalnumbers{%
   \let\@arabic\orig@arabic%
   \renewcommand\thefootnote{\protect\number{\c@footnote}}%
}

\endinput
```

[And here is the link to download Khmer fonts](http://khmer.hawaii.edu/Download/KhmerOSfonts.zip)

Comment: I don't think `beamer` uses `polyglossia`... So I think you will have to adapt `beamer`'s own commands...

Comment: @cfr finally, I found it. The last frame number is stored in `\inserttotalframenumber` and its definition was given in **beamerbasemisc.sty** at lines **42** and **166**. Now, I am able to change it :)

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I found it :)
The total frame number is actually stored in control sequence `\inserttotalframenumber` and its definition is defined in **beamerbasemisc.sty**. To fix this problem, I need to add the following code in my **gloss-khmer.ldf** file:

```
\@ifclassloaded{beamer}{%
    \AtEndDocument{%
        \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\@writefile{nav}%
            {\noexpand\headcommand{\noexpand\def\noexpand\inserttotalframenumber{\khmernumber{\the\c@framenumber}}}}}
    }
}{}
```